# Asking Questions Regarding Fundamentals

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

This is a somewhat related question:

> [Constructive topics and question-asking practice](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142/constructive-topics-and-question-asking-practice)

I have been going back over some basic studies that I did a few years ago before I drifted away from chess. Is it acceptable to ask questions that can be found via Google?

For example I remember a few years ago studying King and Pawn endings via the works of [Karsten Müller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karsten_M%C3%BCller). He would use the terms *key squares* and *critical squares* in a way that it was not clear to me if the two terms were interchangeable. Would it be acceptable to ask for both a definition of the term *key square* and a clarification regarding *critical square* even though I know the answer and the question could likely be resolved via a brief Google search? Of course this is applicable to other fundamental ideas that could be found via a search engine as well. It seems like a question that should be on the SE Chess site...

Even though I already know the answers to the example question, I would not be answering it myself unless it sat unanswered for a few days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it acceptable to ask questions that can be found via Google?

See [this post](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5702/39482) by [Robert Cartaino](http://stackexchange.com/users/34933/robert-cartaino), one of the Stack Exchange team:

> General Reference is intended to dissuade questions that can be easily looked up in a source that is specifically designed to answer that question: "What is the definition of [X]?", "What is the melting point of lead?", "What year did Maryland become a state?" These are not not problems that needs to be solved; They're just a lazily-asked question that can just as easily be looked up. And General Reference is not saying "that question is easily Googleable." Let's not go there.
>
> [Should questions that can be googled be disallowed?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50/should-questions-that-can-be-googled-be-disallowed) <sup><-- will be public shortly</sup>

As well as the post last linked to:

> You should completely remove "This answer is Googleable" from your vocabulary because it is a gross mischaracterization of the issue.
>
> We've experimented with a close reason called "[general reference](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1004/10041)" to rid some sites of ultra-basic questions — questions that are asked in such a lazy fashion as to be easily findable in references designed to quickly and effortlessly find that information.
>
> Question: What is the Qur'an?
> Answer: "Grrr... Why don't you just look it up?!"

Googling per se is not a good enough reason to close a question.

To answer a hypothetical question you raised:

> Would it be acceptable to ask for both a definition of the term *key square* and a clarification regarding *critical square* even though I know the answer and the question could likely be resolved via a brief Google search?

Yes, it would be acceptable.  The ideas and experience of the members of this community will likely be able to clarify and define chess theory in a better, more concise, and more compact way than random (though in some cases worthy) sources found by Google.

It's different from questions such as *What is a Rook?*, since the answer to that question is readily available and has been universally and exhaustively answered to the point at which it **cannot appreciably be improved upon**.

As long as the existing sources are not necessarily available, consistent or exhaustive, your question should be fine.

---

To address the last line of your post:

> Even though I already know the answers to the example question, I would not be answering it myself unless it sat unanswered for a few days.

See Jeff Atwood's blog post on answering your own question - [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).  An excerpt:

> To be crystal clear, **it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged**.
>
> I do it all the time! For example, when I ran into a nasty issue with Java exploits in Google Chrome when browsing for images, I [documented that on Super User by asking and answering my own question](https://superuser.com/questions/201613/disable-java-plugin-in-google-chrome). Now, others can benefit from my misfortune — and best of all, I got new even better answers beyond what I offered! Overall, a huge win all around.
>
> ... Bottom line — **never hesitate to ask and answer your own question on any Stack Exchange site.**

In fact, there's even an option to answer your own question *before* you post it, so when the question is posted, the answer is posted at the same time.  See https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/ask:

> [image]

I would not recommend *immediately* accepting your own answer, though there's nothing wrong with doing so after others have had a chance to answer, and yours is still (to you) the best.  If no one else answers, feel free to accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. I had already seen his post regarding answering your own questions. I was just hoping to get someone's rep up as according to the Area 51 site we still need some more people ranked over 200. I was hoping someone with rep < 200 might respond... We'll see.